# how to debug the matching of the date?

Tags: jodatime, logstash

I am matching events such as

```
[Sun Jan 11 10:43:35 2015][3205.51466981] user idp : testing 10.234.22.220 (10.234.22.220) [61673782]
```

with

```
%{SYSLOG5424SD:timestamp}%{GREEDYDATA}user %{WORD:user} : testing %{HOST:ip}
```

It works, I see the various fields in elasticsearch/kibana. Specifically `timestamp` in the example above is matched with `[Sun Jan 11 10:43:35 2015]`

I now would like to use this match with `date` in order to have the right `@timestamp`.

I tried to use in `filter`

```
    date
    {
      match =>  [ "timestamp", "SYSLOG5424SD" ]
    }
```

but this crashes logstash with an output suggesting to file a bug report - I opened [a ticket](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/issues/2483).

In the meantime I tried to explicitely match the pattern via

```
    date
    {
      match =>  [ "timestamp", "\[EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss y\]" ]
    }
```

As you suspect - it never matches, `@timestamp` is set to the time when the event is logged by logstash.

Can you spot the problem, or is there a clever way to debug such cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The timestamp matching done by the date filter isn't based on regular expressions or grok expressions. That's why putting SYSLOG5424SD there doesn't work. Apart from a couple of special cases listed in the [filter documentation](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date#match) you can only use tokens recognized by the Joda-Time library. See the documentation of the [joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) class.

You were very close to get it right – just don't escape the square brackets:

```
date {
  match => ["timestamp", "[EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss y]"]
}
```

Again, Joda-Time patterns aren't regular expressions so to match square bracket literals you don't need to do anything special. Quoting the Joda-Time documentation:

> Any characters in the pattern that are not in the ranges of ['a'..'z'] and ['A'..'Z'] will be treated as quoted text. For instance, characters like ':', '.', ' ', '#' and '?' will appear in the resulting time text even they are not embraced within single quotes.

Comment: Does it have to be called `timestamp` - the same as in the grok filter?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie In this case `timestamp` is the name of the field you want to parse, so if you're populating that field via a grok filter (which is typical) it needs to match the name of the field extracted with the grok filter.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your second question: yes, there is a clever way to debug such cases, there is an online grok debugger (http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/), and a joda time debugger, I created inspired by the first one: https://java-time-parse-debugger.herokuapp.com/

**Update**: As users are encouraged to migrate to Java 8's DateTime API, I migrated this debuggung web app to use Java 8's DateTime API, without JodaTime any more.

Comment: Adding one example to your site would help a newcomer. Now there's a missing format, fml :(

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie, thanks for the feedback. I updated this app, now with example and a little bit more information.